# Ancient Olympics Top Trumps Style Game

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm trying to recall the name of a game I played approx 6 years ago with friends.  So they game may be older than that.

It is a top trumps style trick taking game themed in ancient olympics.

The game has (I think) 40 card each representing an athlete and shows how good they are in 5 different events.  These rankings I think were numbered 1-40 and each was unique so draws were not possible.

The game with with score tokens for different events which we're in a pile and increased in value.

At the start of the game 2 events were chosen to the the 1st and 2nd events contested.  Players simultaneously chose an athlete from there hand to compete and the card with number closest to 1 won.  (1 being 1st and 40 being 40th)

The winner of the event being contested would take the scoring token, however the last place competitor of the event got to decide which event would be completed at in 2 turns time.

I think there was a mechanic that is you played really bad athletes there was a limited supply of scoring tokens for doing so.

I think they game ended when a certain number of scoring piles for events we're depleted and the player with the highest sum of points of scoring tokens was the winner.

In my head the game had a name similar to 'Olympics' and a year in the name but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [Olympia 2000](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/261/olympia-2000-v-chr)

> players use simultaneously played cards to compete in ancient Olympic events, such as long-jump, discus, or archery. The cards have a picture of the athlete as well as a rating for his skills in each of the different events. Often times, an athlete will be very good at one event and be very poor in others, while some athletes are simply too inept for words, and still others are god-like. The key to the game is using your cards wisely, because although the best athlete gets the prize for the current event, the worst athlete gets to pick the up-coming event.

Comment: Thats exactly it.  As you can imagine googling words "olympic' with 'games' meant my googling wasn't really helping.